# Use AND - operator in the find method

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with the array field.  If I want to find all documents with specific tag I use next query:

```
db.Bookmarks.find({tags : {$regex: "bbb"}})
```

Is it possible find all documents which 2 or more specific tags ?  Something like this:

```
db.Bookmarks.find({tags : {$regex: "bbb"}}).find({tags : {$regex: "ccc"}})
```

or

```
db.Bookmarks.find({tags : {$regex: "bbb" and "ccc"}})
```

**Update**

All documents:

```
> db.Bookmarks.find()
{ "Name" : "Lenta.ru", "Timestamp" : 1380912671423, "URL" : "http://www.lenta.ru", "_id" : "8vJgjH2rKAsyfHPc9", "tags" : [  "aaa",  "bbb" ] }
{ "Name" : "Яндекс", "Timestamp" : 1380912663299, "URL" : "http://www.ya.ru", "_id" : "39o2BvPHgEHkzvS4Y", "tags" : [  "aaa",  "ccc" ] }
{ "Name" : "Google", "Timestamp" : 1380912656968, "URL" : "http://www.google.com", "_id" : "MkCYfEn3WenpFvQcm", "tags" : [  "aaa",  "bbb",  "ccc" ] }
```

I want to get all documents with tags "bbb" and "ccc" simultaneously.  Something like

```
db.Bookmarks.find({tags : {$regex: "bbb" and "ccc"}})
```

Result will be:

```
{ "Name" : "Google", "Timestamp" : 1380912656968, "URL" : "http://www.google.com", "_id" : "MkCYfEn3WenpFvQcm", "tags" : [  "aaa",  "bbb",  "ccc" ] }
```

Comment: Check the `$in` statement

Comment: There's a couple ways to interpret what you're looking for.  Could you show some example docs and which should match your desired query?

Comment: @Eran Medan, $in statement works like 'OR'- clause.  I will get all documents where tag have one of the values in the array.  But I need the documents where tag have all of the values in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#op._S_all) query operator to do this:

```js
db.Bookmarks.find({tags: {$all: ['bbb', 'ccc']}})
```

You can use regular expressions as well.  To include tags that start with c instead:

```js
db.Bookmarks.find({tags: {$all: ['bbb', /^c/]}})
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine $all operator and $regex operator ? User can pit only first characters of tag.  For example, db.Bookmarks.find({tags: {$all: ['bbb', 'c']}})  must return equal result as db.Bookmarks.find({tags: {$all: ['bbb', 'ccc']}}).  Is it possible ?

Comment: @demas I don't know specifically about the `$regex` operator, but regular expressions can be used as shown in the updated answer.